# Cannot overload function

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

So I've got a templatized class and I want to overload the behavior of a function when I have specific type, say char. For all other types, let them do their own thing. However, c++ won't let me overload the function.

Why can't I overload this function? I **really really do not** want to do template specialization, because then I've got duplicate the entire class.

Here is a toy example demonstrating the problem: http://codepad.org/eTgLG932

The same code posted here for your reading pleasure:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

struct Bar
{
  std::string blah() { return "blah"; }
};

template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
public:
  std::string doX()
  {
    return m_getY(my_t);
  }

private:
  std::string m_getY(char* p_msg)
  {
    return std::string(p_msg);
  }

  std::string m_getY(T* p_msg)
  {
    return p_msg->blah();
  }

  T my_t;
};

int main(int, char**)
{
  Foo<char> x;
  Foo<Bar> y;
  std::cout << "x " << x.doX() << std::endl;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

Thank you everyone for your suggestions. Two valid solutions have been presented. I can either specialize the doX method, or specialize m_getY() method.

At the end of the day I prefer to keep my specializations private rather than public so I'm accepting Krill's answer.

Comment: void doX returns something. Please, fix this.

Comment: Q: What compiler?  Q: What's the exact error message?  Q: do you think the two "m_getY()" functions might conflict when T == char? ;)

Comment: @KirillKobelev Good catch, just a typo on my part. I fixed that and updated everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your method `m_getY` a member function template. And them make specialization of this  function template for `char*` or simply define a method with a `char*` argument. In this case you will not have to duplicate the whole class.

Comment: The standard is very explicit that template of the function and simple function with fixed types of parameters can coexist in the overload bucket.

Comment: @KirillKobelev this ("simple function with fixed types of parameters") is not a specialisation of a template, contradicting your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I improved my post. Unfortunately I was thinking about different things when I was writing the answer and the comment.

Answer (score 7):

You can specialize just one function out of an entire template class on a specific type without specializing the entire class.  It would look like this:

```
template <> void Foo<char>::doX() {
     /* custom implementation here */
}
```

You rarely see this in practice, but this is totally legal C++ code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 This works as long as the member function is not also a template itself.

Comment: I also tried this. This works in MSVC. Although this is really really bad feature. @templatetypedef, is this explicitly allowed by the standard?

Comment: @KirillKobelev- Yes, this is allowed by the standard.  I don't think it's a "really really bad feature;" it's just unusual.

Comment: @templatetypedef, allowed is close to "not denied". The question was about "explicitly allowed". If would a member of C++ comettee, I would vote down this feature. With fixed types, this is just an unelegant work around the prohibition to have these 2 methods in the template class in the first place. I will try this for partial specialization.

Comment: Partial specialization (original class template has 2 params; method specialization fixes only one param) it does not seem to work in MSVC. @templatetypedef, do you think it should?

Comment: @KirillKobelev- No, this should not work.  The language spec specifically allows full specializations this way, but not partial specializations.  I honestly don't know why.

Comment: Thanks. This is a little bit better that partial specs are not allowed. Then for me this 'specialization' is nothing but a simple method that was introduced in the original post... Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 3):

```
  std::string m_getY(char* p_msg)
  {
    return std::string(p_msg);
  }

  std::string m_getY(T* p_msg)
  {
    return p_msg->blah();
  }
```

The problem here is that when `T` is `char`, you end up with two functions with identical signature.

Comment: Doh. Its so obvious now that you point it out. I guess my brain stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string m_getY(char* p_msg)
{
  return std::string(p_msg);
}

template<typename U> 
std::string m_getY(U* p_msg)
{
  return p_msg->blah();
}
```

will not conflict with each other (and the former is *not* a specialisation of the latter, as it is not a template)