# Explicit specialization of non-class, non-function members of a class template

Tags: c++

Look at the code:

```
template <class x> struct Foo
{
    int getX(x *p) { return(0); }
    enum E12 { a };
};

template <> int Foo<int>::getX(int*)
{
    return(-15);
}

template <> enum Foo<int>::E12
{
    a, b, c
}
```

As it was discussed in [Cannot overload function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268535/cannot-overload-function), the first specialization is legal and even works in MSVC. While the second specialization for `enum` does not even want to compile, saying "error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition".

It seems to me that C++ is making relaitively unlogical exception for methods. Enum is just an example. The same thing can be applied to member classes, typedefs, etc.

I will be happy is some body will comment on this.

Comment: @MooingDuck, Thanks for pointing at wrong syntax. Fixed.

Comment: Ups, the comment above should be to @Potatoswatter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very obscure new feature of C++11. File a bug report with Microsoft, although it is unlikely it will be given priority as almost nobody is aware this is allowed. The correct syntax would be

```
template <class x> struct Foo
{
    int getX(x *p) { return(0); }
    enum E12 { a };
};
 
template <> int Foo<int>::getX(int*)
{
    return(-15);
}
 
template <> enum Foo<int>::E12
{
    a, b, c
};
```

I've [filed a bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53815) with GCC. Can someone test on recent Clang?

---

In C++03, only classes and functions may be explicitly specialized. From the standard, C++03 14.7.3/1:

> An explicit specialization of any of the following:
>
> - function template
> - class template
> - member function of a class template
> - static data member of a class template
> - member class of a class template
> - member class template of a class or class template
> - member function template of a class or class template
>
> can be declared by a declaration introduced by `template<>`

A member enum is not such a case. (Generally speaking, an `enum` type is always defined only once at its first declaration.)

To obtain a templated `enum` or `typedef`, you can wrap it in a class template. In your case, it would be a member class template of `Foo`. Such a construct is called a metafunction.

C++11 also has alias templates, which are like templated typedefs, but they cannot be explicitly specialized.

---

The policy of only allowing classes and functions to be specialized, and then allowing such templates to encapsulate other things like `enum` and `typedef`, seems more consistent to me than allowing direct specialization of `enum`. But, perhaps the language is going in your preferred direction.

Comment: @MooingDuck They very quietly added a bullet point to 14.7.3/1 making it legal. I'd be interested to see the proposal paper, since the feature looks hard to justify on the face of it.

Comment: The question was not C++11. I tried with MSVC 2008 after fixing syntax once again. It is saying now "error C3113: an 'enum' cannot be a template" at the point of instantiation attempt.

Comment: @KirillKobelev Sorry, this was a confusing coincidence. I had no idea about this C++11 feature until I looked closer at my original answer. I'll re-post it as an addition to the current answer.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, No problem. Thanks for your participation.

Comment: >  enum type is always defined only once at its first declaration. Ha-ha. Enums perfectly allow forward declaration.

Comment: @KirillKobelev Sounds like a Microsoft extension. GCC appears to allow `enum blah;` *after* the definition, not before, but that is also non-conformant.

Comment: (Note, however that forward declaration of an enum is never needed, because you can always use an elaborated-type-specifier. To declare a variable of undefined `enum` type, it would be `enum blah my_blah;`. That's completely different. In C++11 an `enum` used this way must have `int` as the underlying type, IIRC.)

Comment: Forward declaration for enums IS needed because it allows using name of the enum in the named-type-specifier. This is convenient. I use this often.

Comment: @KirillKobelev Uh, "named-type-specifier" doesn't name a grammatical construct. Did you just make that up? Anyway, you can use `enum blah` almost anywhere you can use `blah`. Only exceptions that come to mind are functional cast notation and pseudo destructor call..

Comment: For some time is was qurious why BNF grammar from the C++2003 standard has in the rules for enum header a `simple-or-qualifeid-id` and not simple `identifier`? Later on I found out that the follwing works fine: `class B { enum E; }; enum B::E { a,b,c, };`. Once the same works for methods and member classes, why should this be prohibited for enums?

Comment: @KirillKobelev Don't base your understanding of the grammar on experiments with MSVC.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, come on. I never thought like that. I think you misunderstand the role of the standard. This is a piece of paper written by people. With typos, bugs and misunderstandings. Yes, it is useful and it should be respected. But it does not come from GOD.

Comment: This code is actually ill-formed, no diagnostic required. The `Foo<int>::` triggers implicit instantiation of `Foo<int>`, which implicitly instantiates the definition of `Foo<int>::E12`, meaning that it can't be later explicitly specialized. See the example in §14.7.3 [temp.expl.spec]/p6.

Comment: @T.C. Almost, but not quite. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/20110225/153285 . Implicit instantiation of `Foo<int>` does not trigger instantiation of `E12` because it's not used by any member declaration in `Foo`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter No, implicitly instantiating a class template implicitly instantiates the definition of unscoped member enumerations (14.7.1/p1). If you look at the second half of the example in 14.7.3/p6, particularly the line marked "ill-formed, `A<char>::E` was instantiated when `A<char>` was instantiated", it's basically the same situation as your code.

Comment: @T.C. Ah, unscoped enumerators! Thanks, I'll update this after I wake up.